# Work visa required for Italy if married to an Italian Citizen?

Tags: italian-citizens

I have dual citizenship, Australian and Italian, and I live in Australia. My husband is an Australian citizen and has been offered a job in Italy. It is to work in a movie for about 2 months. I will be traveling with him. 
My question is regarding the type of work visa he would need and if being married to an Italian citizen makes it easier?
I would love to know the process and how long it usually takes. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: For such short-term travel, our sister site about [Travel](//travel.stackexchange.com) would probably be a better place to get an answer. But posting the same question in multiple sites in the network is discouraged, because people might waste time answering a question that's already been answered. I suggest that you [search there](//travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=italy+work+visa) to see whether it's already answered, and if not use the "flag" link to request that the moderators migrate this question across.

Comment: Legally, he doesn't need a work visa *if you accompany him to Italy,* but practically, it may be easier just to apply for the work visa he would need as any Australian.  Will you be in Italy while he is working there?

Comment: Yes, I'll be accompanying him in Italy.